# Does .bash_profile get run with su --login if the user has no shell specified?

Tags: linux, shell, bash

On Ubuntu I created a system user with a home directory but no password, like this:

```
sudo useradd -r -m foobar
```

That created the user `foobar` with home directory `/home/foobar` just like I wanted. The user has no password, forcing me to switch from another user, which is what I wanted:

```
sudo su --login foobar
```

So far so good. But I see in `/etc/passwd` that **`foobar` has no shell specified**. But it has the expected `.bash_profile` scripts in the generated home directory. So my question is: when I switch to `foobar` using `sudo su --login foobar`, does `.bash_profile`, `.bashrc`, and the like get executed?

The answer appears to be "yes". The aliases defined in `.bashrc` are present. And the `SHELL` environment variable is set to `/bin/bash`. So everything seems to be OK.

Perhaps the second question is, "but why"? Does `su --login …` always use the shell of the user *invoking* `su`? Or only if the target user has no shell specified?

Comment: SO is for programming questions. Use unix.stackexchange.com or superuser.com for Unix tech support questions.

Comment: This is not on-topic for Stack Overflow, as defined in [help/on-topic], but you may be able to get help on [unix.se] or [su].